# Making flip-flops using logic gates in Proteus - I'm getting gray (unknown) signals

Tags: pcb, digital-logic, logic-gates, flipflop, proteus

for my school project i have to use Proteus to design my circuit. My professor told us that we cannot use any flip-flops and if we had to use them we should make them by using logic gates. I'm trying to make JK flip flops but I'm getting gray signals in the areas shown in picture. Can someone help me how can I get this flip-flop to work?

[image: JK Flip Flop]

Comment: What does gray signal mean? Why is that bad? What logic gate types those are, 74, 74LS, 74HC, some other type?

Comment: @Justme I used the one Digital Primitive ones that came with Proteus, their names are AND, NOR, AND_3 etc.

Comment: @Justme Gray signal means unknown signal so it's neither 1 nor 0

Comment: Undefined state has to be defined First. Then it will work.. Wait i'll write an answer.

Comment: @SadatRafi thanks a lot, I couldn't define it because proteus doesn't let me set an initial state for that node

Comment: It’s probably an initial condition issue. Do they have an initial condition field when you double click on the logic gates? If not, put a 10k pull-up on the output of the U3 NOR gate.

Comment: @user110971 I have tried that. It's not working.It's causing a logic race condition. Is the circuit correct?

Comment: @SadatRafi What’s the time stamp of the loop? When U5 becomes high U4 and U2 form a logic loop.

Comment: I am manually checking outputs by putting 1/0 as input. I have found the race condition. But I can't solve it. Let the output of U3 as 0. The clock is set 1. for the falling edge of the input pulse, you will find the race condition.

Comment: @SadatRafi If there is a loop, then the circuit is wrong.

Comment: Try switching in the component settings the simulation method from digital to analog, that sometimes helps.

Answer (score 1):

> *Can someone help me how can I get this flip-flop to work?*

With J and K inputs set high (red squares) the output of a JK flip flop is not truly defined - it is in the toggle condition and, the current state of its outputs is defined by the earlier values of \$Q\$ and \$\bar{Q}\$ on the previous clock edge: -

[image]

Picture [link](https://circuits-diy.com/jk-flip-flop-circuit-using-74ls73-truth-table/).

So, maybe that is what the grey squares are telling you?

Maybe you need to add a preset input to define the initial state as in this SR flip-flop: -

[image]

Picture [link](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/sequential/conversion-of-flip-flops.html).

Or as per this alternative version of the JK flip-flop: -

[image]

[Link address](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffourier.eng.hmc.edu%2Fe85_old%2Fhomework%2Fhomework3_key%2Findex.html&psig=AOvVaw3Z9eATSWoyssWzTBXm4FIg&ust=1590317294212000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CA0QjhxqFwoTCMi_2PvnyekCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAP).

Comment: But the question is about how to simulate it. I am trying his T flipflop to run in proteus. But it is not working in any way.

Comment: @SadatRafi the question is *Can someone help me how can I get this flip-flop to work?*. Please leave your answer when you get your simulation working.

Comment: @Andyaka hi, thanks for the answer! I added a preset and clear input like you showed in the picture but as soon as I turn preset to 0 Proteus gives me an error saying "Logic race condition detected during transient analysis."

Comment: @Fingol31 keep at it is my advice - it might be a quirk of Proteus. I'm not in any way an expert on Proteus so I can't say.