# PROTEUS 8.9 version Error: No model specified for CLOCK#000C

Tags: circuit-analysis, simulation, clock, flipflop, proteus

I did everything on my project, but I am getting these errors. How can I fix it?

```
No model specified for CLOCK#000C.
Simulation FAILED due to partition analysis error(s).
```

[image: schematic in Proteus]

Comment: You need to contact the fast help department.

Comment: Hello sir but i dont know how can i contact with them i just sign up today,can you please tell me how can i contact with them?

Comment: It looks like this is only a small section of the circuit. I can't see anything to do with CLOCK. Have you put this name on a net or something? You can always go to the Labcenter website and use the forums, or go to the help files and there is a customer service email address and phone number if you are desperate for quick assistance

Comment: You have used a component specified as 'No Simulation Model'

Comment: Hello,yes it is a part of counter circuit these flipflop infrastuctures linked to logic gates and they are linked to the 7segment display for counting from A to J. But the other part of circuit work correctly i have just problem with this part.

Comment: Sadat Rafi how can i fix it sir?

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/501424/making-flip-flops-using-logic-gates-in-proteus-im-getting-gray-unknown-signv

Answer (score 4):

[image]

You must have picked a piece of equipment labeled as 'No Simulation model. Now, if you place this component in your circuit, then there will be an error named - "No model specified for ... "

[image]

[image]

Here 'No model specified for U1:A' means that the IC named U1:A is not approved for simulation. You need to replace it with active component.

[image]

So you need to replace the faulty IC with an active one. I have replaced it with the spice model. And the error is gone.

[image]

In proteus, almost everything has a generic model. If there is no simulation model for your desired component, then do your simulation using another component that has the same characteristics. For designing PCB, just change the package.

Comment: Thank you for everything sir but it still doesnt work can you help me on whatsapp(+90 532 131 44 26)  or zoom ? please contact with me i need help .@SadatRafi

Comment: Sorry. I prefer discussion here. If you are using Proteus 8, then you may send your file through email.

Comment: Or you can share through google drive.

Comment: sir please send me an email fertural@gmail.com i will shre thi document on google drive with your email @SadatRafi

Comment: your file is 8.9. Mine is 8.6 :(